# How to use regular expressions with Eclipse's find/replace to refactor code

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace

I'm still developing my regex skills, so I'm leaning on the community.  I say I want to refactor code "with Eclipse", but I've used a number of IDE's whose search and replace functions accept regular expressions.  I've successfully create general expressions to find things, but wonder if I can take portions of the matched pattern and use in the replacement value.  For example, I have a lot of test functions named with the following pattern" "testSomeFunction1(), testSomeFunction2(), testAnotherFunction()"  I'd really like them to be named "test_someFunction1(), test_someFunction2(), test_anotherFunction()".  The Find: is "test[A-Z]", but what do I use for Replace with:?  "test_[a-z]" is literally replacing?  Perhaps, I cannot use a regex statement in the replacement?

Comment: I'm curious: since you already have an assumption on what you need to do, why don't you just try it out in Eclipse?

Comment: Thanks Sandman.  I should have been clear.  I have already tried it and failed.  Hence the reason for asking for help.

Comment: Did you try capturing and back-referencing groups as shown in my answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the sample text you've posted, the find expression should be `test([a-z]*)` and the replace should be `test_$1`.

This makes use of captured groups referenced by `$i` where `i` is the captured group index (`0` is the entire expression). You may also want to consider the case of the search string since text like `permuteString` will also match the expression if the search is case-insensitive.

You should also be able to use content-assist in the text fields of the `Find/Replace` dialog to see what options are available for regular expressions (once you've checked the box for `Regular expressions`) - press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>

Comment: Thanks!  It helps to actually know the terms to search for "back-referencing groups"  The more I learn the more I realize how much I don't know.

Comment: You're welcome. I found the [Java regex tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to be a good starting point - it's specific to Java of course, but a lot of concepts are quite general.

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to check out the \C regular expression operator, which I think is specific to Eclipse.  It saves a lot of work in replacing the same word in upper-case, lower-case, and camelCase variants.  For example, if the original text is:

```
   SomeObject someObject = SOMEOBJECT;
```

then doing a "Replace All" replacing

```
    someObject
```

with

```
    \CanotherObject
```

will get you:

```
    AnotherObject anotherObject = ANOTHEROBJECT;
```

which is probably what you want.